# Unreachable code detected [WebAPI]csharp(CS0162)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Please help me, i have been working with this error for a couple for my project. I have not found a solution for this

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCities()
    {
        throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
        **var** cities = await uow.CityRepository.GetCitiesAsync();
        var citiesDto = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CityDto>>(cities);
        return Ok(citiesDto);
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem? You throw an error on the first line so.... what are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code unconditionally executes:

throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();

This means that any code after that will never be accesses.  Hence the warning "Unreachable code detected".  I guess you should have something like:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCities()
    {
        if (IsUserAuthorised() == false)
        {
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
        }
        **var** cities = await uow.CityRepository.GetCitiesAsync();
        var citiesDto = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CityDto>>(cities);
        return Ok(citiesDto);
    }
```